# SAP Cloud Platform SDK for Android - Android studio not found when installing on a Mac

Tags: android, cloud, sdk, sap, platform

After following the [instructions](https://help.sap.com/doc/c2d571df73104f72b9f1b73e06c5609a/Latest/en-US/docs/user-guide/getting-started/installing.html) for installing the SAP Cloud Platform SDK for Android on my Mac I have encountered an issue when running the installation script. The error message says *"Android studio was not found"* although I have downloaded and run Android studio multiple times already on this Mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Being new to using macOS this took me a while to figure out and might be an obvious solution to others, but I managed to fix the issue by moving the Android Studio Application to the "Applications" folder on my Mac. After doing so the installation script works as expected.

Comment: mark this as answer then

Comment: @Suncatcher I had to wait 2 days to accept it ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯